# reload/refresh directive to update view in html in angular7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am uploading a image in database and this image is saved there and returns same url everytime for this (url is fixed). I want to refresh this  directive so that image is updated in everywhere .html(views) in app . In short, I am trying to do something like as soon as image is uploaded, `directive` get refreshed and all components using this directive also update their view simultaneously.

How to achieve this?

## directive.ts

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[app-userprofileimage]'
})
export class UserprofileImageDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef,
        private user: UserService) {
    }
    @Input() set setProfileImage(userId) {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', this.user.baseUrl + "/api/1.1/getMediaStream/profilePictures/" + userId + "/profile.jpg?" + this.setProfileRnd()); // this url does not change
    }

  setProfileRnd() {
    return 'rnd=' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(7);
  }
}
```

## app.component.html

```
<img class="profileImageIcon" 
          app-userprofileimage [setProfileImage]="currentUserDetail['id']">
```

Comment: Does it's source valu change?

Comment: yes, images are changing everytime when we are uploading it.......but since they return same url everytime...........src="" attribute of image tag is holding correct url but old view in every component where this directive is used

Answer (score 0):

Please use changedetectionstrategy in your component
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy
and use `this.ref.detectChanges()` every time you update your url

Comment: Here, the scenario is like this nothing changes. Only thing is changing is image view while image url always remains the same. Only thing we know that when image is being uploaded and when image upload done. I am trying to do something like as soon as image is upload directive get refreshed and all components using this directive also update their view.